# SPSS Syntax - Identify duplicate responses and systematically identify cases to keep

Tags: spss, data-management

I have a large set of survey data in SPSS where around 15% of respondents answered the survey more than once (this was not intended).  I have formulated a systematic method to determine which cases to keep but am not sure how to write the loop to perform this task.

The variables I have are:

- ID: unique identifier for every individual (some repeated submissions)
- SurveyComplete: 0/1 (is the survey complete)
- Duplicate: 0/1 (are they a person who submitted more than one survey)
- PrimaryFirst: 0/1 (identifies first submission)
- MatchSequence: integer (numerical indicator of which submission number the survey is)
- Date: date of submission
- keep: 0/1 (yet-to-be-created indicator of whether or not the record is being retained)

Here are what my data look like:

```
ID  SurveyComplete  Duplicate  PrimaryFirst  MatchSequence    Date   keep
123       1             1            1             1        07162015  .
123       1             1            0             2        07182015  .
456       0             1            1             1        07152015  .
456       1             1            0             2        07192015  .
789       0             1            1             1        07112015  .
789       0             1            0             2        07182015  .
789       0             1            0             3        07212015  .
012       1             0            1             1        07122015  .
```

Theoretically, I would like to determine the following in the order below:

1. IF Primary = 1 AND SurveyComplete = 1 THEN keep = 1.  Other submissions for this ID keep = 0.
2. ELSE IF Primary = 0 AND SurveyComplete = 1 THEN keep = 1.  Other submissions for this ID keep = 0.
3. ELSE (where SurveyComplete = 0 for all responses) keep most recent submission.

And here is the resulting keep column:

```
ID  SurveyComplete  Duplicate  PrimaryFirst  MatchSequence    Date   keep
123       1             1            1             1        07162015  1
123       1             1            0             2        07182015  0
456       0             1            1             1        07152015  0
456       1             1            0             2        07192015  1
789       0             1            1             1        07112015  0
789       0             1            0             2        07182015  0
789       0             1            0             3        07212015  1
012       1             0            1             1        07122015  1
```

Ideally I would like to be able to complete this in SPSS syntax without plugins as my work doesn't take kindly to software add-ons.  Any help that can be provided is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every step an AGGREGATE function determines for every ID if a decision was already made. An ID that already has a decision will be taken out of the game, undecided IDs go on to the next step:

```
* creating fake data to play around with.
* note I added an extra line for ID=456 to demonstrate choice between multiple non-primary lines.

DATA LIST list (", ") / ID SurveyComplete Duplicate PrimaryFirst MatchSequence Date.
        begin data
        123, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7162015
        123, 1, 1, 0, 2, 7182015
        456, 0, 1, 1, 1, 7152015
        456, 1, 1, 0, 2, 7192015
        456, 1, 1, 0, 3, 7192015
        789, 0, 1, 1, 1, 7112015
        789, 0, 1, 0, 2, 7182015
        789, 0, 1, 0, 3, 7212015
        12, 1, 0, 1, 1, 7122015
        end data.
        execute.

* now starting work on defining the KEEP variable.

        if (PrimaryFirst = 1 AND SurveyComplete = 1) keep=1.
        if (PrimaryFirst = 0 AND SurveyComplete = 1) NotPrimarySeq=MatchSequence.
        aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables /break=ID /decided=max(keep)/NotPrimarySeq_min=min(NotPrimarySeq).

        if missing(decided) and (PrimaryFirst = 0 AND SurveyComplete = 1) keep=(NotPrimarySeq=NotPrimarySeq_min).
        aggregate/outfile=* mode=addvariables overwritevars=yes /break=ID/decided=max(keep)/Date_max=MAX(Date).

        if missing(decided) keep=(date=date_max).
        recode keep (miss=0).
        execute.
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!  Could you please clarify one thing for me?  The /decided command does not seem to be a part of the aggregate command.  Is this a separate line I need to compute outside of the aggregate command?

Comment: One additional question.  In the second set of syntax where I'm deciding to keep the next complete survey, what ends up happening is that it will keep all complete surveys (i.e., if survey 1 is not complete, but 2 and 3 are, it will mark 2 and 3 both as keep when I just want to keep 2).  Thank you in advance!

Comment: I added a fix for the problem - Please consider updating your question to include this additional detail.